# How do I read UserSecrets using ABP?

Tags: c#, configuration, aspnetboilerplate

I can see that the secrets get pushed into some kind of storage for the configuration, but I don't understand how to access the variable. 
During config building, I can see that it read my app secret, but later when I inject `IConfiguration` into an App Service, the key is not there.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class EmailAppService : MyAppServiceBase, IEmailAppService
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

    public EmailAppService(IConfiguration Configuration)
    {
        _configuration = Configuration;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Signup just involved sending an email to Rhyse at the moment.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Users email</param>
    [AbpAllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<Response> SignupToBetaAsync(SignUpToBetaInput input)
    {
        // from https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/csharp.html
        var apiKey = _appConfiguration["SENDGRID_API_KEY"];
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
        var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        var to = new EmailAddress("fakeemail@gmail.com", "Example User");
        var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        return await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
```

Some documentation about how to do this would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that worked for me in the end is using this guide:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/05/user-secrets-in-a-net-core-web-app.html

example secrets.json:

```
{
  "Authentication": {
    "Google": {
      "ClientId": "baerbaeb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "ClientSecret": "bahababbtY8OO"
    },
    "Microsoft": {
      "ApplicationId": "barberbaerbaerbaerb",
      "Password": "aerbaerbaerbaerbaerb"
    }
  },
  "Sendgrid": {
    "ApiKey": "aerbaerbaerbearbearbaerbeabeabr"
  }
}
```

Azure Application Settings would be formatted like this:

```
Authentication:Google:ClientId
Sendgrid:ApiKey
```

Add some config classes.

```
public class GoogleApiConfig
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
}
```

Then register them like this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.Configure<GoogleApiConfig>_appConfiguration.GetSection("Authentication:Google"));
    services.Configure<MicrosoftApiConfig>_appConfiguration.GetSection("Authentication:Microsoft"));
  services.Configure<SendgridApiConfig>_appConfiguration.GetSection("Sendgrid"));
```

Then just inject `IOptions<MicrosoftApiConfig>` and use as normal - simple and strong!

Answer (score 1):

Injecting `IConfiguration` won't get you the user secrets.

Use the static method `AppConfigurations.Get` and specify `addUserSecrets: true` instead:

```cs
public class EmailAppService : MyAppServiceBase, IEmailAppService
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;

    public EmailAppService()
    {
        _appConfiguration = AppConfigurations.Get(WebContentDirectoryFinder.CalculateContentRootFolder(), addUserSecrets: true);
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the Web projects, you can inject `IHostingEnvironment` and use the extension method:

```cs
_appConfiguration = env.GetAppConfiguration();
```

Comment: @aaron it turns out this solution doesn't work when deployed to Azure. I get the same error as in this github issue https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-templates/issues/43